# ContextMenuStrip On RightClick, IF Items Are Selected In Listview?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I have a ContextMenuStrip attached to a list view, and it's working great, but what I'm interested in knowing is how I can have it show up only when one or more items are selected in the listview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`Opening`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening.aspx) event. The event args has a Cancel property so that you can examine the state of your application and decide whether to have the menu show (by doing nothing) or prevent it from showing (by setting `e.Cancel = true`). However, like @Grzenio mentions, I would find it more intuitive if the item that i right-clicked on became selected automatically.

Another option would be to use the `Opening` event to populate the context menu with only one disabled item, with a text like `(no item is selected)` or so; this would inform the user about why the command is not available.

Comment: I used this with if(List.SelectedItems.Count == 0){e.Cancel=true;}
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For other people reading this thread, a nice way is to gray out the options in the menu (in Opening event) when no items are selected instead of not displaying the menu at all

```
if (List.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
{
    // e.Cancel=true;
    List.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
    List.Enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me its intuitive that if you have no items selected (or you right-click on a non-selected item), the item would get automatically selected just before you show the context menu.

If the first solution is not acceptable, I think I would try to attach the ContextMenuStrip when items get selected and detach it when they are unselected.

Comment: The only problem (and it is very minor) is that if a user right clicks the listview's column headers, the menu still shows up.  I will try to implement your second suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
   Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseUp
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right And ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Dim cn As New ContextMenuStrip()
            cn.Items.Add("Apple")
            Me.ListView1.ContextMenuStrip = cn
            cn.Show(Control.MousePosition.X, Control.MousePosition.Y)
        End If
    End Sub
```